# Is there a typedef for "unsigned long long int" in C?

Tags: c

I want to use the method `strtoull(...)` but do I really have to type out `unsigned long long` whenever I use it?

The largest integer typedef I could find was `uint64_t` / `size_t` but it is not the same as `unsigned long long`.

I believe `unsigned long long` takes up to much space. Is there some sort of official and recognized shortcut for it among the community?
Do I have to make my own type? What would be a good name for it? `u128int_t` or `uLLong`?

Comment: As far as I know `long long` is 64-bits, so `uint64_t` is what you want.

Comment: Do you need a specific number of bits?  [Because `unsigned long long int` is not guaranteed to be any larger than 64 bits](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.2.4.2.1)

Comment: The U in uint64_t means unsigned

Comment: @AndrewHenle do you mean that `unsigned long long int` is guaranteed not to be any ***smaller*** than 64 bits?

Comment: Why do you want a typedef for it? What if `long long` is less than 128 bits? On most modern platforms, `long long` is 64 bits and `long` is either 32 bits (then `int64_t` points to `long long`), or 64 bits too (then `int64_t` could point to either).

Comment: I don't understand your question.  Are you asking, A) "I have `unsigned long long` and I want a suggestion for a better (shorter?) name for it." or is it B) "I need exactly 64 bits and I want to know which type to use"  Or something else?  And FYI: `sizeof(unsigned long long)` is your friend for determining how many bytes it is in your implementation.

Comment: @WeatherVane I meant the `long long` modifier but since the question asked about unsigned it's be `uint64_t`.

Comment: @WeatherVane No.  I meant it's not guaranteed to be larger than 64 bits.  It *can* be larger, but it doesn't have to be.

Comment: @AndrewHenle updated my question - thank you for pointing out what part confused you.

Comment: Re the question edit, `unsigned long long int` is perfectly readable. Do you mean it is boring to type it? If so, you can use a `typedef` during development and then edit to replace for final version.

Comment: @WeatherVane if used very frequently I find it to take too much space and I thought that there might be some sort of official shortcut for it that I am not aware of.

Comment: Then the problem is very different, and nothing to do with types.

Comment: @WeatherVane How can I best rephrase my question?

Comment: @sueszli *Do I really have to type out unsigned long long whenever...*  The amount of time you spend actually typing out code is a very small percentage of the time it takes to actually develop any working implementation.  Your brain is not going to be able to come up with sound, reliable, readable, understandable code faster than you can type.  How many times could you have typed `unsigned long long x = strtoull(...);` in the amount of time you've spent on this question?  And the amount of screen space it uses up is really pretty much irrelevant.

Comment: Use an intelligent editor and you'll find you rarely have to _"type out"_ anything.  Cut and paste, auto complete, etc. are awesome.  Your goal should be to write the most readable, correct, and maintainable (resistant to change) code you can.  You may not like that it's called "unsigned long long" but that's what it's called.  If another coder encounters a typedef in your code whose only purpose is keystroke-savings and not improved semantics, e.g. just abbreviated like `ULL` or `ullint` or `intsixtyfour` they're just going to be surprised and have to go look up your typedef.

Comment: @AndrewHenle and Wyck This makes a lot of sense to me. So introducing a new typedef to save a couple of characters would just add more confusion to the maintainers of my code in the future. Got you! Thank you for your in depth response!

Comment: @sueszli type "uLLong" when you first create the code and the replace all with `unsigned long long`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You say you "need a type for `unsigned long long int`", but `unsigned long long int` *is* a type.

Apparently your concern is that the name `unsigned long long int` is too long to type. You have a point, but defining an alias for it is likely to cause more confusion than it's worth. Every knowledgeable C programmer knows what `unsigned long long int` means. Nobody knows what your alias means without looking it up, and even then they can't be sure the meaning won't change as the software evolves. If you want to use `unsigned long long int`, it's best to use `unsigned long long int` (or `unsigned long long`).

You can define your own `typedef`. Remember that `typedef` doesn't define a new type. It only defines a new name for an existing type.

`uint64_t`, defined in `<stdint.h>`, may or may not be an alias for `unsigned long long int`, depending on the implementation. `unsigned long long int` is guaranteed to be at least 64 bits, but it could be wider (though I know of no implementations where it's not exactly 64 bits wide). Similarly, `uintmax_t` is likely to be `unsigned long long int`, but that's not guaranteed either.

You can define an alias if you like, but I wouldn't recommend it *unless* you need a name for some type that just happens to be defined as `unsigned long long int`. If you can give your typedef a name that has meaning within your application, that's probably a good idea. If its only meaning is "a shorter name for `unsigned long long`, I'd advise against it.

If you need a 64-bit unsigned integer type, `uint64_t` already exists; just use that. (And if the implementation doesn't provide a type with the required characteristics, then it won't define `uint64_t` and the error message when you try to use it will tell you that.)

Comment: "Defining an alias just to have shorter name is likely to cause more confusion than it saves." -> this is the part that answered my question best. Please highlight it if possible. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> *Do I have to make my own type?*

You can `typedef`ine whatever name you wish for whatever type (inside the defined naming rules of course), keep in mind that this is only an alias for the original type, hidding predefined types behind `typedef`s is not consensual, it is legal though.

> *u128int_t or uLLong?*

Taking the above paragraph in consideration, `uLLong` is perfectly fine. As of today there is no primitive 128 bit wide type in C, `u128int_t` would be misleading, I would avoid it.

`uint64_t` is guaranteed to have 64 bits, `unsigned long long int` is not, it has to have ***at least*** 64 bits, but it is not guaranteed by any rule that it should have ***only*** that.

Comment: So this means that making this type would not ensure me actually getting that much space but it is legal and semantically correct?

Comment: Sure, `uLLong` is perfecty fine, `u128int_t`  would be misleading, both are legal.

Comment: Thank you so much! - It bothers me that functions like `strtoull` exist even though its uncertain whether the machine even has this amount of memory available for this primitive type. I cant wrap my head around it :(

Comment: A `typedef` is just that: another name for the same type. If you do `typedef X Y;` the only thing you are doing is telling the compiler that `Y` actually means `X`. What you choose to `typedef` is up to you. But you shouldn't use confusing or reserved type names for that matter (`_t` is reserved for POSIX and so on).

Answer (score 0):

Some compilers (for example gcc) support 128bit integers as an extension

example:

```
__int128_t mul(__int128_t x, __int128_t y)
{
    return x * y;
    
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/c8bW1xYdh